# Where does Orchard CMS stored content definition?

Tags: orchardcms, orchard-modules, orchardcms-1.10

I am fairly new to Orchard CMS.
I am going through how a module is created an got a question.

According to the documentation, content definition could be created in two ways:

1. use admin content definition page
2. create module project in visual studio

is there any difference?

I created a test content definition and try to find it in the SQL compact database. I can't seem to find it.

Anyone know where that info is stored?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find the content definition in the following tables in the Orchard database:

- `Settings_ContentFieldDefinitionRecord`
- `Settings_ContentPartDefinitionRecord`
- `Settings_ContentPartFieldDefinitionRecord`
- `Settings_ContentTypeDefinitionRecord`
- `Settings_ContentTypePartDefinitionRecord`

The admin interface uses the same APIs that are used when defining content definition from code, so it's basically the same thing. I tend to define content definition in migrations, as that's the best way to ensure that content definition changes are properly applied on all instances of the application (the migrations automatically run during application startup). The admin interface is intended for users who do not have access to the source code (ex. administrators, not developers).